# GTiff to PNG conversion- Gdal Python

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-translate, png

I am trying to convert a Gtiff image to PNG using Gdal in python with `gdal_translate`.

My gtiff has the following properties:

```
Width   255
Height  255
Data type   Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point
GDAL Driver Description GTiff
GDAL Driver Metadata    GeoTIFF
```

while my PNG has:

```
Width   255
Height  255
Data type   UInt16 - Sixteen bit unsigned integer
GDAL Driver Description PNG
GDAL Driver Metadata    Portable Network Graphics
```

and the results are strange like the following image.

[image]

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: Change into 16 bit in inevitable because PNG supports only 16 bits or less https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/. Scaling to 16 bit should not create artifacts, though. Perhaps the issue is in somewhere else. Does the image perhaps have totally black areas and nodata value set to 0?. De-activate nodata in your viewer and holes should disappear.

Comment: This is a satellite image. For some reason, where I Translated Gtiff to png, the transparency band in QGIS was set to one satellite band, specifically to nir band. I changed to None and it was fixed. The transparency band can be found in Preferences > Transparency > Transparency band

Comment: I believe that PNG format does not support 4 data bands, only 1 or 3 bands + optional alpha. Use `gdal_translate -b 1 -b 2 -b 3...` for selecting only the first 3 bands.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the stats of the geotiff and your exact gdal_translate command, i.e `gdalinfo -stats your.tif` and `gdal_translate -of PNG etc...`

Answer (score 0):

Just add '.png' in the name path

Comment: you changed float to Uint16, this is the reason

Answer (score 0):

First thing I had to do was to assign the output type as `gdal.GDT_Byte`. Also, the *format* argument should be assigned to 'PNG'. If one uses keyword arguments for *gdal.Translate* this is what worked for me:

```
kwargs_gdal = {'format': 'PNG',
               'xRes': xRes,
               'yRes': yRes,
               'outputType': output
               }
```

where output is `gdal.GDT_Byte` and xRes, yRes is the output resolution of the image, for example 10 meters.
Afterwards, you just pass kwargs_gdal to `gdal.Translate` as follows:

```
gdal.Translate(new_image_name.png, old_image_name.(tiff or something), **kwargs_gdal)
```

That's all.